# Complex Oracle SQL to sum data

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

I am building a SQL query in Oracle 10g that needs to sum overtime hours for the base table, but needs fields from the parent tables as well. I am looking for the fastest way to build the query. The Project_ID in the first three tables is the same, where the Work_ID is one-to-many to the fourth table.

```
Table J
Project_ID VARCHAR(6)
J_Title VARCHAR(25)

Table K
Project_ID VARCHAR(6)
K_Title VARCHAR(25)

Table L
Project_ID VARCHAR(6)
L_Title VARCHAR(25)
Work_ID VARCHAR(6)

Table C
Work_ID VARCHAR(6)
L_Title VARCHAR(25)
CHRG_DT DATE
WRK_HR NUMBER(5,2)
```

My best guess looks like this (It's simplified, and the date is actually passed as a variable to the stored procedure):

```
SELECT
 J.J_Title,
 K.K_Title,
 L.L_Title,
 L.Work_ID,
SUM(CASE WHEN TRUNC(C.CHRG_DT) = TO_DATE('09/27/2013', 'mm/dd/yyyy') THEN C.WRK_HR END) AS WRK_HR
FROM C,
L,
K,
J
WHERE J.Project_ID = 'ABC'
AND K.Project_ID = J.Project_ID
AND L.Project_ID = K.Project_ID
AND C.Work_ID = L.Work_ID
GROUP BY L.Work_ID,
L.Project_ID,
K.Project_ID,
J.J_Title,
K.K_Title,
L.L_Title
```

UPDATE: Omitted two fields in Table C. Changed Group By fields, and added Work_ID to output for clarity. Sorry for changes, I have to type this from another network, can't just cut and paste. Also trying to leave out unrelated fields.

This is the output I am getting:

```
J_Title K_Title L_Title Work_ID WRK_HR
------- ------- ------- ------- ------
JOB_ABC KO_ABC  LO_ABC  DEF         30 
JOB_ABC KO_ABC  LO_ABC  DFG          3
```

This is the output I am looking for:

```
J_Title K_Title L_Title WRK_HR
------- ------- ------- ------
JOB_ABC KO_ABC  LO_ABC      33
```

Comment: Have you actually *tried* that? Does it work?

Comment: Yes, but it groups by Work_ID, and I need it to group by Project_ID. I need help with the structure and optimizing; I am thinking a subquery that SELECTS from table C for each row of Table L will be really slow.

Comment: Can you post the complete table definitions. Your query is referencing columns that are not part of your definitions.

Comment: My mistake. Added omitted fields.

Comment: @CigarDoug: Would you be able to add a simple sample of the *current* output, and a simple sample of the *desired* output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be able to get the results you want with:

```
select j_title, k_title, l_title, sum(wrk_hr) from
(
  SELECT
   J.J_Title,
   K.K_Title,
   L.L_Title,
   L.Work_ID,
  SUM(CASE WHEN TRUNC(C.CHRG_DT) = TO_DATE('09/27/2013', 'mm/dd/yyyy') THEN C.WRK_HR END) AS WRK_HR
  FROM C, L, K, J
  WHERE J.Project_ID = 'ABC'
  AND K.Project_ID = J.Project_ID
  AND L.Project_ID = K.Project_ID
  AND C.Work_ID = L.Work_ID
  GROUP BY L.Work_ID, L.Project_ID, K.Project_ID, J.J_Title, K.K_Title, L.L_Title
)
group by j_title, k_title, l_title;
```

Comment: That works, thanks. I understand you have to include fields in the Group By statement to pass them to the parent query, but does the order of the Group By matter?

Comment: @CigarDoug: The order of columns in `GROUP BY` normally does not matter (try it out with some test data and see!), but if you start including grouping functions (http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets.php#grouping_functions) such as `ROLLUP` or `CUBE` then it *can* matter.